# GCP stackdriver logging not showing the "global" resource

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, google-cloud-stackdriver

Three weeks back, I was setting up a dialogflow-Node.js project and deployed the project onto Google cloud functions. I was also able to direct the 
error/debug logs to the "Global" resource of Google Stackdriver logging.

Yesterday, I've set up the same project once again and deployed to cloud functions as a separate project, but now I am not able to see the "Global" resource in stackdriver. I am able to see other resources like Google Project, Cloud Functions, etc but not Global.

I tried with two different google accounts. I was not able to direct my logs to any other resources in stackdriver, except for Global resource, now I'm not able to find the "Global" resource also.

The metadata for directing the logs to "global" (was working) and to "cloud_functions" resource (never got it working) are below.

1. Directing to "global"

```
const metadata = {
  severity: 'ERROR',
  resource: {
    type: 'global'
  }
};
```

2. Directing to "cloud_functions"

```
resource: {
  type: 'cloud_functions',
  labels: {
    function_name: "app"
    project_id: "<ProjectId>"
    region: "us-central1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you write logs but can't see them ? Did you try to follow steps described [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/quickstart-sdk#write-log-entries-using-sdk) - you should be able to read the my-test-log with no problems.

Comment: i was able to publish logs to Global, but for new projects, i am not getting the Global resource

Comment: Can you provide some actual code that you try to deploy ? From what you provided I can't tell anything...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue, not seeing a *Global* resource.

Comment: @slhck I tried from a separate google account as well, but there also it was not showing

Comment: In my case the issue was a bit different: I logged to the wrong (nonexisting) project ID, but the logging library didn't raise any errors.  The global scope appeared once I logged to the correct project.